# CodeIgniter echo model function from array

Tags: codeigniter-3

Guys I have a question let's assume that I have below

```
$data =array (
       'user' => '$this->mymodel->getUsers(),
```

);

If I echo $user in view it doesn't work I get array to string conversion error

Comment: Error is pretty much self-explanatory. `$user` variable is an array (of array or of objects depending of model's `getUsers()` retrieval method). `var_dump($user);exit;` or `print_r($user, 1);exit;` to debug and check structure of retrieving data.

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER** :

```
$data = array(
    'user' => '$this->mymodel->getUsers(),
);
```

It depend on your model

**MODEL 1** :

```
function getUsers(){
    return $this->db->get('table_user')->row();
}
```

**VIEW** for **MODEL 1** :
`echo $user;`

**MODEL 2** :

```
function getUsers(){
    return $this->db->get('table_user')->result();
}
```

**VIEW** for **MODEL 2** :

```
foreach ($user as $row){
    echo $row->user_name;
}
```

because the second model return an array.
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

actually if you use `$return $yourVariable->result();`
in your model. You must use  `foreach ($user as $yourvariable)` in your view.

if you use `$return $yourVariable->row();`
you can use `echo $user` in your view.